# The Given Path's Format Is Not Supported In Viewing Image

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm having a problem in viewing image from folder path. I don't know how can I fix this. I've tried to have use

#### My Code

```
String Path = @"C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\ProjectName\image-folder\mypicture.jpg";

picturebox_view.Image = Image.FromFile("'" + Path + "'");
```

I receive the following error that says

```
The Given Path's Format Is Not Supported...
```

When I tried to debug and check the value of my "Path" it appears that its wrong. The result is this

```
String Path = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\...";
```

I tried to have Path2 with replace argument but it doesn't appear to be working in me.

## Here's my replace code (Not Working)

```
String Path = @"C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\ProjectName\image-folder\mypicture.jpg";

String Path2 = Path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
picturebox_view.Image = Image.FromFile("'" + Path2 + "'");
```

Thanks in advance my fellow programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the debugger showing a C# string literal.  The string doesn't actually have double slashes.

Your real problem is that there is no `'C:` drive.  Don't put quotes around a path.